# How can I left align the table captions in the list of tables in my book class document

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, alignment, book-class

Some of my table captions are long and they cause some words to have too much space between them. I think they would look much better if the captions were left aligned in the list of tables. I think the `tocloft` package can do that, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. Could someone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know that you can provide a short caption title in order to prevent such long entries in the ToC/LoF or LoT? I.e. `\caption[Foo title]{This is my very long title that is not shown in the LoT because it is too long!}` -- I think this is the easier way than fiddling with `tocloft` settings

Comment: Yes, thank you. That would be a good solution I can use when it is my document. Unfortunately, I can't do that, as this is something I am doing for someone else who wan'ts to retain the long title.

Comment: Tell her or him, that this is not the best strategy and annoys readers most likely. The importance of a ToC/LoF/LoT is to give a quick overview about the contents and not novel-like lengthy descriptions

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283730/left-align-toc-items-when-using-tableofcontents.  You might be able to put a \parbox into the short caption, if you knew how wide to make it.